# why this function is not working? Showing error of val of null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

the function is getting called from the modal table. and the table body is accessed by ajax. in this table two each of the rows is carrying two textboxes. Its IDs are different for each row and each textbox. I will show my codes below.

the **ajax function** is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /////////////// Invoice Link Click ////////////////
    $("#invoice").click(function(){

        var rowID=[];

        ///////// Initialize and assign row row value /////////////
        rowID = arrays;
        var tempArrays='';
        for(i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
        if(arrays[i]!=''){
            if(tempArrays!=''){
                tempArrays=tempArrays+','+arrays[i];
                }
            else{
                tempArrays=arrays[i];
                }


            }
        }

        alert("SUCCESS ALERT" +tempArrays);

        alert(typeof tempArrays);
        if(rowID!=''){
            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Ajax_calls/invoicingFetch',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{tempArrays:tempArrays},

                success: function(data){

                    $('#newtest').html(data);
                    alert("SUCCESSFULLY RETURNED............!!!!!!!!");

                    }
                });

            }


        });
    });
```

*In* **AJAX Controller** *Function* :

```
public function invoicingFetch(){
    if(isset($_POST['tempArrays'])){
            $output='';
            $postedVal=$this->input->post('tempArrays');
            $myArray = explode(',',$postedVal);

            $this->load->model('Ajax_model');
            $arrayLen=sizeof($myArray);
            for($i=0;$i<$arrayLen;$i++)
            {
                $arre=$myArray[$i];
                $records = $this->Ajax_model->getRawdataGDSSingle($arre);
                foreach($records as $row){
                    $saleid='sale'.$row->slno;
                        $marginid='margin'.$row->slno;
                    $output.='

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center !important;"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$row->slno.'"  /> </td>
                        <td>'.$row->NAME.' </td>
                        <td>'.$row->TOTAL.' </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="'.$saleid.'" name="saleamount" onKeyPress="UpdateMargin('.$saleid.','.$marginid.','.$row->TOTAL.')" onChange="UpdateMargin('.$saleid.','.$marginid.','.$row->TOTAL.')" value="'.$row->TOTAL.'" /> </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="'.$marginid.'" name="marginamount" onchange="UpdateSale('.$marginid.','.$saleid.','.$row->TOTAL.')" value="0"  /> </td>
                        <td>'.$row->BKD_BY.' </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td>'.$routing.' </td>
                        <td>'.$row->A2L.' </td>
                        <td>'.$row->TKT_NUMBER.' </td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                    }
                }

            echo $output;  ///this output is the table body in modal
            }
     }
```

*The* **script** *on the Modal page header*

```
function UpdateMargin(saleid,marginid,total){
    var sales=document.getElementById(saleid).value;
    //var margin=document.getElementById(marginid).value;
    var total=total;
    var salMargin=sales-total;
    document.getElementById(marginid).value=salMargin;
    }
```

The **error** that showing in console is 
[image: Showing Error as **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null**]

Showing Error as **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null**

Anybody could tell me the reason? why it's happening? Thanks in advance to all brilliants.....

Comment: Anybody could check this?

Comment: probably your demanded ID element has no value. Does `$row->TOTAL` always is a value? On which event does the error occur?

Comment: UpdateMargin function having error according to console. but in your snapshots there is no UpdateMargin function

Comment: what is the value of arrays? and also can you share your html if you think that is relevent

Comment: @AndréKelling on both onkeypress and onchange are showing error. but in source tool, it is showing the values as passed. its showing as UpdateMargin(sale1765,margin1765,1110)

Comment: @NegiRox its there in console. but showing error. the value passed as shown like this. then also showing error .UpdateMargin(sale1765,margin1765,1110)

Comment: @NarendraMongiya arrays are there in ajax call only. that area is working fine. here what i am needed is i want change the textbox value as per the other textbox change. that html area is there in ajax controller function

Comment: it meanse you are simply confuse between javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
var sales=saleid.value;
```

instead of

```
var sales=document.getElementById(saleid).value;
```

Answer (score 4):

`.val()` is an JQuery function.

But you're fetching the element without JQuery.

So if `var margin=document.getElementById(marginid).value;` works, you have to change the `.val()` code into `var sales = $( '#' + saleid  ).val();`

If getting .value didn't work, either the element does not have a value ( maybe it's not an input element ) and you're looking for innerText or innerHTML or some data property.

If none of the above is true, saleid is probably not a valid id in your HTML.

Comment: its showing the error as this when made the changes you said Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: now i just added an alert in the function with saleid. it alerted [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: on that ajax controller function the value is passing could you check it?

Comment: that means that saleid is an element already instead of a string representing the id of that element.

Comment: The solution in the JQuery way would have been: `var sales = $( saleid  ).val();` without the hash, so the element would get wrapped as a JQuery element. THis would be equivalent to `var sales=saleid.value;`. I would suggest to change the name from saleid and marginid to saleelement and marginelement inside the updateMargin function, so their names are correct instead of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are trying to get from an element does not exist in the DOM. Please check the element with saleid(whatever you are passing) exists or not

Comment: i have checked . its carrying the value as [object HTMLInputElement]. what should i do to change this?

Comment: Please check saleid[0] or saleid.value using alert.

Comment: `saleid.value` will give you the value